# Minha descrição da linha de cima não está aparecendo!

Tags: css, front-end, angular, angular-material

[image: A descrição dos itens da linha de cima não está aparecendo! Se alguém puder me ajudar a resolver isso eu ficaria agradecido.]

```
    <md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds "flex="30"> <!-- cada cartão ocupará 1/3 da página(33)   -->
        <img ng-src="{{classified.image}}" alt="">

        <md-card-content>
               <div class="classified-info" ng-show="!showContact">          
                    <h2 class="md-title"> {{classified.title}}</h2>
                    <h2> {{classified.posted | date :'longDate'}}   </h2>
                    <h3>{{classified.price | currency}}</h3>
                    <p>{{classified.description}}</p>
               </div>

               <div class="classified-info" ng-show="showContact">
                <p> <md-icon class="mdi mdi-account">  </md-icon>{{classified.contact.name}} </p>
                <p> <md-icon class="mdi mdi-phone">  </md-icon>{{classified.contact.phone}} </p>
                <p> <md-icon class="mdi mdi-email">  </md-icon>{{classified.contact.email}} </p>    
               </div>

               <div layout="row">
                <md-button ng-click="showContact = true"
                ng-show = "!showContact">
                Contact
                </md-button> 

                <md-button ng-click="showContact = false"
                ng-show="showContact">
                Details
                </md-button>    

                <md-button ng-click="showAdmin = true"
                ng-show="!showAdmin">
                Admin
                </md-button>

                <md-button ng-click="showAdmin = false"
                ng-show="showAdmin">
                Close
                </md-button>

               </div>   

               <div class="classified- admin" ng-if="showAdmin">
                   <h3>Admin</h3>
                   <div layout="row">
                       <md-button class="md-primary"> Edit</md-button>
                       <md-button class="md-warn"> Delete</md-button>
                   </div>
               </div>
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Que linha, naum entendi... Dá mais detalhes

Comment: Os 3 produtos superiores tem descrição também como na linha debaixo.
Mas, não está aparecendo.